# jquery add class to all elements if there are more than 3 with the same x position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website with multiple columns. Each column can have 0-10 rows.
The rows contain various elements but always have a specific element that is at the same x position in every row.

I want to identify all rows that are in a column with more than 3 rows. I would therefore like to loop over all of those "special" elements and add a certain class if there are more than 3 elements with the same x position:

```
let xPositions = []
let specialElements = $("span[aria-label='specific text']")
specialElements.each(function() { 
    xPositions.push(this.x) // obviously this.x does not work. How can I get x?
})
specialElements.each(function() { 
    let count = xPositions.reduce((cnt, val) => val == this.x ? cnt + 1 : cnt)
    if(count > 3){
        this.addClass('highlight')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that I might be naive, but I understand the x as position relative to parent container, maybe use jquery position function:

```
elPosition = $(this).position();
xPositions.push(elPosition.left);
```

Comment: It is actually $(this).offset().left

Comment: ok, the offset is relative to the document, thanks for approving ;)